# How to check whether a file is exists in any one of the folders of the root directory

Tags: php

I have a root directory (probeta).In that, again I have 3 sub folders like `hr,admin,super`. How to check a file is exists in any of these 3 folders??

I tried this code..but it always goes to `super/notifications/filename..``

```
<?php
$dir="../super/notifications/";
$dir1="../admin/notifications/";


if(file_exists($dir. $row['file']))
{       
            ?>
         <a href='../super/notifications/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>' target='_blank' >View Details</a>
<?php
}
else if(file_exists($dir1. $row['file']))
{       
            ?>
         <a href='../admin/notifications/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>' target='_blank' >View Details</a>
<?php
}
else 
{       
            ?>
         <a href='../hr/notifications/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>' target='_blank' >View Details</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

//Please help me out...
And is there any way to store a file into there 3 folders while a file uploading  into database??

Answer (score 0):

check all your condition in if statement

```
<?php
$dir="../super/notifications/";
$dir1="../admin/notifications/";
$dir2="../hr/notifications/";
if(file_exists($dir. $row['file'])|| file_exists($dir2. $row['file']) || file_exists($dir2. $row['file']))
{      ?>
 <a href='<?php if(file_exists($dir. $row['file'])) echo $dir;else if(file_exists($dir1. $row['file'])) echo $dir1;else if(file_exists($dir2. $row['file'])) echo $dir2;?>/<?php $row['file']; ?>' target='_blank' >View Details</a>
```

Comment: if file exists in one of these 3 paths ,it only goes to ..super/notifications/.But        I want to go to corresponding folders...For example if file exists in ../hr/notifications/,then a href be like ../hr/notifications/..

Comment: It doesn't work..It shows like this... probeta/employee/$dir/

Comment: remo '' and make it adsecho $dir